# Show that P(A∩B)=P(A)∩P(B)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

Let S∈P(A∩B),then S⊆(A∩B).
Thus,S⊆A and S⊆B.
Thus,S∈P(A) and S∈P(B).
Thus,S∈P(A)∩P(B).
Therefore,P(A∩B)⊆P(A)∩P(B).

My question is:
Since I've shown "S∈P(A∩B) and  S∈P(A)∩P(B)", does  this also imply that "P(A)∩P(B)⊆ P(A∩B)" ?Therefore the proof could already end here.

Let Q∈ P(A)∩P(B),then Q∈ P(A)  and Q∈ P(B).
Thus,Q∈ P(A)∩ P(B).
Therefore, P(A)∩P(B)⊆ P(A∩B).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Is $P$ the power set?

Comment: Yes,it is.$P$ is the power set.

Comment: It should be "Let $S\in \mathcal P(A\cap B)$, so thus $S\subseteq A\cap B$."

Comment: You have not shown "$S\in P(A\cap B$ and $S\in P(A)\cap P(B)$". You have shown $S\in P(A\cap B)\implies S\in P(A)\cap P(B).$ The 2nd part is to show $S\in P(A)\cap P(B)\implies S\in P(A\cap B).$

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, that is the case.

Let $S\in\mathcal P(A\cap B)$.

This equates to $S\subseteq A\cap B$.

This equates to $S\subseteq A$ and $S\subseteq B$.

This equates to $S\in\mathcal P(A)$ and $S\in\mathcal P(B)$.

This equates to $S\in\mathcal P(A)\cap\mathcal P(B)$.

Therefore, $\mathcal P(A\cap B)\subseteq\mathcal P(A)\cap\mathcal P(B)$ *and also* $\mathcal P(A)\cap\mathcal P(B)\subseteq\mathcal P(A\cap B)$, *by reason that every step is an equivalence*.

Thus $\mathcal P(A\cap B)=\mathcal P(A)\cap\mathcal P(B)$.

---

Now compare and contrast with the case for union.

Comment: In contrast, the analogous statement for unions is true if and only if either $A \subseteq B$ or $B \subseteq A$. Indeed, if neither set is contained in the other, then $A \cup B$ itself is contained in neither $A$ nor $B$, but it is contained in $A \cup B$.

Comment: Thanks for your correction!However,you've shown that $S\in\mathcal P(A\cap B)$ is equivalent to $S\in\mathcal P(A)\cap\mathcal P(B))$,hasn't this already proved it?

Answer (score 2):

Just an add on ( to Graham Kemp's answer).

The answer to your question ( in the body of the post) is "no".

Having proved one direction ( namely --> ) is not sufficient.

Since you want to prove an equality , which amonts to a double and reciprocal inclusion, since inclusion translates as a conditional, your goal is to prove a bi-conditional.

The fact you said " thus"  means that your proof is " one way" only, and requires a second part, for <--- directon.

As Graham Kemp notes , the only way to end the proof at the point you indicate is to use equivalences instead of simple implications ( " thus"). And *here* you are allowed to do this, since the steps are reversible.

A series of equivalences is a series of ( valid) bi-implications, and since bi-implication is transitive, it turns out that the two ends of the chain are equivalent. But these two ends are precisely the two propositions you want to link with a biconditional. So, your goal is reached.

More on : material implication, bi-implication / logical implication, bi-implication ( that is equivalence) see : Seymour Lipschutz, Set Theory ( Chapter on Algebra of Propositions) ( at archive.org).